# Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) on Appstore crashlog

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

Im keep getting this crash over and over and Im out of clues for weeks now. Any insights would much appreciate to see what im missing out here. Code snippet where it shows as follow with the Error Log.

[image]

Code where it crash

```
 func validateFormFields (){

  var formType: FORMS_TYPE? = .LOG

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
 
             //Where this crashes i guess according to the Error Log 
            if FormsValidationManager.shared.validate(tableView: self.tableView, presentVC: self, formType: self.formType!) {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    SwiftSpinner.show("Saving prospect form")
                }
                    //Save Prospect Form
                    self.formsViewModel.saveProspect(tableView: self.tableView, self.contactList) {
                      
                      self.formDataCompletionDelegate?.relaodTableData(formType: .PROSPECT)
                      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //Exit Prospect form
                        
                    }

            }
        }
   }
```

Code inside the FormsValidationManager.shared.validate class as follow

```
 func validate(tableView: UITableView, presentVC: UITableViewController, formType: FORMS_TYPE) -> Bool {

    if formType == FORMS_TYPE.LOG {//Log form validation

        let logFormCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
        if logFormCell != nil {
            textFieldValues.append(anotherDict: getTextFieldValues(enumType: LOG_FORM_TF_TAGS.self, cell: logFormCell))//add values to dict

            if let validationMessage = getValidationMessage(textFieldValues: textFieldValues, formType: formType, cell: [logFormCell!]) {
                Utils.shared.addReloadAlert(message: validationMessage, presentVC: presentVC, title: Constants.ALERT_TITLE)
                return false//form is invalid
            }
        }
        

    }  
 }
```

Supportive method as follow

```
private func getTextFieldValues<T: RawRepresentable & CaseIterable>(enumType: T.Type, cell: UITableViewCell?) -> [String: String?] where T.RawValue == Int {

    var textFieldValues: [String: String?] = [String: String?]()

    for (_, element) in enumType.allCases.enumerated() {
        if let textField = cell?.viewWithTag(element.rawValue) as? UITextField {

            let caseLabelName = getEnumCaseLabelName(value: String(describing: enumType.init(rawValue: element.rawValue)))

            if textField.text!.isEmpty {
                textFieldValues.updateValue(nil, forKey: getTextFieldName(value: caseLabelName))
            } else {
                textFieldValues.updateValue(textField.text, forKey: getTextFieldName(value: caseLabelName))
            }

        }
    }

    return textFieldValues
  }
```

Comment: For a general discussion see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/understanding_the_exception_types_in_a_crash_report

Comment: You suggest that the error is in `validate()` but the crash report seems to be saying that it’s crashing in `validate(tableView:presentVC:formType)`, in line 52 of `FormValidationManager.swift`.

Comment: correct and the validate(tableView:presentVC:formType) method is pasted above and not sure what im missing there

Comment: Which is line 52 of `FormValidationManager.swift`?